# Holt-Winters vs. comparison to history

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality

I have a timeseries with daily and weekly seasonality that I want to check for anomalies (on data as it comes in live). I could use Holt-Winters forecasting, or I could just compare the data with the same time at the previous week.

What would be the advantages/disadvantages of those two strategies?